# Segmentation fault in C program and stops running further

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to run a link list program in C using Visual Code but after running it, it is giving me a segmentation fault error.

Additionally, it gets stopped on running code.

Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
int main()
{

    struct node *head = NULL, *newnode, *temp;
    newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter any no:");
    scanf("%d",&newnode->data);
    printf("%d is inserted in Link List...",newnode->data);
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You overwrite `newnode` with `head` which is NULL, then dereference it.

Comment: Unrelated to the segfault, `choice` has no initial value, so `while(choice)` may or may not be true.

Comment: You should change that to `do { ... } while (choice)`

Comment: Please focus on an actual question about  a single problem. You seem to be aware, that you are mentioning two separate ones. Simplify your code to only inserting one node, i.e. drop the loop for now. Compare https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ Then have a thought about dimich comment. Maybe you can create your own answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question; now that you learned that comments are unsuitable for that.... What is the desired output for the simplified code? What is the output you get? Please try for [ask].

Comment: The code doesn't even segfault anymore!

Comment: Looks like you solved the problem on which you appreciatedly focused this question. Since you did not get an answer yet, you can consider refocusing on the other problem. By providing a [mre] which focuses on that one. Make sure to only demonstrate the next problem, without including the alreay solved one. I recommend, in order to minimse confusion, to delete this question and create a new one on the next problem.